# Does documentation for old ArcGIS Pro versions remain available online?

Tags: arcgis-pro, documentation

I have a suspicion that [`arcpy.CreateFeatureClass_management()`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm) has one more parameter at ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2 than it did at ArcGIS Pro 2.0.

Is the ArcGIS Pro 2.0 Help still available online to check this?

I would have expected to find it linked at the [Documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/documentation/) page like the old documentation for ArcMap is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the old help is available online, however, if you want to see what has changed for **tools**, you can visit the appropriate **History** section of the toolbox the tool resides in.

[Data Management Toolbox History](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/data-management-toolbox-history-pro.htm)

Per that link, yes, Create FeatureClass has a new parameter, `out_alias` added at 2.1 to the end.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with Pro the 'What's new' section is the only way to find differences between versions.

For your question, the [What's new in ArcGIS Pro 2.1](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm) page says that a new parameter has been added to the Create Feature Class tool (allowing you to set an alias). So, this parameter is new to 2.1 indeed.