# Finding documentation for changes to syntax/parameters of ArcPy tools/functions in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, documentation

In a Q&A on this site I recall @KHibma pointing out where in the ArcGIS Pro Help any changes to the syntax (like extra parameters) of a particular tool/function since ArcGIS Pro 1.0.0 could be found.

I have searched hard to try and relocate that Q&A without success so, if my recollection is correct, can anyone point me at where to find that documentation or that Q&A (which this will be a duplicate of)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [help from @Midavalo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329282/finding-documentation-for-changes-to-syntax-parameters-of-arcpy-tools-functions#comment538636_329282) I located the earlier Q&A that I was looking for at [Does documentation for old ArcGIS Pro versions remain available online?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273988)

The Help page that best answers my question is [About the toolbox history tables](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/about-the-toolbox-history-tables.htm):

> The documentation for all standard toolboxes in ArcGIS contains a
>   toolbox history topic that catalogs changes made to tools at every
>   release.